# Not able to post a new list Item to SP list using SP-REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am having issues adding a new list item to SP.  I am making an XMLHttpRequest, however I am getting the following message:

`"message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The HTTP header Content-Type is missing or its value is invalid."}`,

I am not sure why, if id do it with jquery ajax I get the following:

`The maximum number of bytes allowed to be read from the stream has been exceeded. After the last read operation, a total of 1049600 bytes has been read from the stream; however a maximum of 1048576 bytes is allowed.`

The string that I am sending to SP is `1,165,755` long.

**Ajax Call :**

```
            var sniffer = contentObjectforSPOL.Content.length;

            var item = {
                "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.SPsiteNameListItem" },
                "Title": contentObjectforSPOL.Title,
                "CTCDescription": contentObjectforSPOL.Description,
                "CTCContentKeyWords": contentObjectforSPOL.KeyWord,
                "CTCSummary": contentObjectforSPOL.Summary,
                "CTCXML": contentObjectforSPOL.Content,
                "CTCApproved": "Pending",
            };



      $.ajax({
                url: "https://tenant.com/sites/SPsiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                data: JSON.stringify(item),
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    FeedBackMessage("Successfully Submitted");
                    clearForm();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    MessageWindow();
                }
            });
```

**XMLHttpRequest:**

```
            var sniffer = contentObjectforSPOL.Content.length;

            var item = {
                "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.SPsiteNameListItem" },
                "Title": contentObjectforSPOL.Title,
                "CTCDescription": contentObjectforSPOL.Description,
                "CTCContentKeyWords": contentObjectforSPOL.KeyWord,
                "CTCSummary": contentObjectforSPOL.Summary,
                "CTCXML": contentObjectforSPOL.Content,
                "CTCApproved": "Pending",
            };

            var url = "https://tenant.com/sites/SPsiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items";
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open('POST', url, false);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-RequestDigest", $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val());
            xmlhttp.responseType = 'application/json;odata=verbose';
            xmlhttp.onloadend = function (e) {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var stop = 0;
                }
                else {
                    errorResults.Location = url;
                    errorResults.ErrorCode = xmlhttp.status;
                    errorResults.ErrorResponseText = xmlhttp.statusText;
                    ErrorHandler(errorResults);
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.onerror = function (error) {
                MessageWindow();
            };
            xmlhttp.send(item);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `content-Type` in `headers` not as `$.ajax` property. I mean

```
headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
```

## Modified Code

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://tenant.com/sites/SPsiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        FeedBackMessage("Successfully Submitted");
        clearForm();
    },
    error: function(data) {
        MessageWindow();
    }
});
```

Also read more about adding item in my [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API).

Comment: Read your article it is very detailed, even though that was a problem.  I think that the problem may also be that the string exceeds their limit if 1048576, I think I need to split the string.  However, I am not sure if I can validate the string as accurate once in SP.

Comment: I am unsure about how to proceed with actually splitting the string

Comment: for which field it is exceeding the limit?

Comment: The field that gives me the problem is "CTCXML": contentObjectforSPOL.Content.  I looked at "Merge" however it replaces the current content in that column.

Comment: Would you think getting it done in csom will solve this issue

Comment: You can try. I believe the result will be same

Comment: Yup, I tried it in csom, and it did push it up success fully.  Thank you

Comment: glad to hear that!